# Swift : Performing operations on certain elements of an array

Tags: arrays, swift

So, something is bugging me with the syntax in Swift for performing operations on Arrays of Ints.

What I wanna do is this : I have an array of Ints which is outputted from a function, its size (count) varies between say 2 and 6 for now, depending on buttons I press in my app.

For each array that is outputted and that contain n ints, I want to create n arrays on which to perform an other action later on.

These "sub" arrays are supposed to be calculated this way :

newArray1's values should be array's values - the value of the first index of newArray1

newArray2's values should be array's values - the value of the second index of newArray2 
etc... (I'll automate the number of newArrays according to the array.count)

An other condition applying for those new arrays is that if at a given index the value is negative, I add 12 (so it'll occur for newArray2 at index 1, for newArray3 at indexes 1 & 2, etc... as long as those newArrays are created).
Here's how I wanted to perform that (I created this with dummy arbitrary array in the playground for the sake of testing before inserting the correct stuff in my app code) :

```
var array : [Int] = [2,4,6,8,9]

var newArray2 = [Int]()
var increment2 = Int()

increment2 = array[1]

newArray2 = array.map {$0 - increment2}
for i in 0..<newArray2.count {
    if array[i] < 0 {
        newArray2[i] = array[i] + 12
    } else {
        newArray2[i] = array[i]
    }
}

print(array)
print(newArray2)
```

So of course it doesn't work because I can't seem to figure how to correctly perform operations on Arrays...
Intuitively it seems in my first if statement I'm comparing not the element at index i but i itself, not sure how to reformat that though...

Any help is most welcome, thanks in advance ! :)

[EDIT: I just edited the names of newArray1 to newArray2, same for increments, so that I have negative values and it matches the index value of 1 which is the second element of my main array]

Comment: Please share the expected outcome for your example.

Comment: in this particular example my newArray2 is supposed to be [10, 0, 2, 4,5]

Comment: (because : my increment2 is the value at array[1], so I want newArray2[0] = 2-4+12 ; and all the others getting just subtracted 4, so : 0,2,4,5

Comment: Matt as I just explained in details in my question, for now I'm trying just to perform my operation on 1 array before creating the others inside a loop. If my operation doesn't work on 1 array it most definitely won't on several so I'm first trying to understand how to perform my operation on 1, and in the example I provided in details it is called newArray2,, is supposed to be mapped from array, then I try to subtract the increment (which is index 1 of array, in this case 4) and inside the loop I'm trying to add 12 when the value is negative, here index 0 of newArray2 is supposed to be -2

Comment: @matt the logic can easily be inferred : increment1 will be index 0 of array, which is = 2 ; then increment3 = 6, increment4 = 8, increment5 = 9 ; then newArray1 should be [0,2,4,6,7], newArray3 after being inserted in the if statement should be [8, 10, 0, 2,3] ; newArray4 should return [6,8,10,0,1] and newArray5 [5,7,9,11,0] if I'm not mistaking

Comment: @matt ok I must have explained it in a terrible manner then... let's try again : I have my array [2,4,6,8,9] ; if I'm not wrong, array[0]=2, array[1]=4, etc... ; my newArray1 is basically my array to which you would subtract the value of the 1st index (or in programming languages index 0), which is in my arbitrary example 2, right ? so newArray1[0] = 2-2 = 0, newArray[1] = 4-2 = 2, and so on ; same for newArray2 : you subtract the 2nd value of array, which is array[1]=4, so newArray2[0] = 2-4= -2, newArray2[1] = 4-4 = 0, etc... and so on

Comment: @matt then once all these new arrays are built, whenever at any given index the value is negative, I want to add 12 : so -4 becomes 8, etc...

Comment: basically I'm just asking you guys how to do a subtraction on some elements and an addition on others, it's not more complicated than that yet nowhere on google I've been able to find that basic stuff, it seems people use arrays only to sum them or reduce them or remap them, I just want to create a new set of arrays from an existing one and perform basic operations on these new arrays... I should re-check my phrasing in my original comment because apparently I explained it in a terrible way

Comment: I re-checked and I really wrote it : "An other condition applying for those new arrays is that if at a given index the value is negative, I add 12 " ; but maybe as my post was quite long you overlooked it, I gotta learn how to make more concise yet precise posts then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to mean this:

```
let arr = [2,4,6,8,9]
var results = [[Int]]()
for i in arr.indices {
    results.append(arr.map {
        var diff = $0-arr[i]
        if diff < 0 { diff += 12 }
        return diff
    })
}
// results is now:
// [[0, 2, 4, 6, 7], 
// [10, 0, 2, 4, 5], 
// [8, 10, 0, 2, 3], 
// [6, 8, 10, 0, 1], 
// [5, 7, 9, 11, 0]]
```

Comment: thanks Matt that's it! 
Ok I'm analyzing this and this shows me I need to learn more about the syntax, but in the Apple Developper documentation I can't seem to find why we have to write [[Int]] and not just [Int] ?

Comment: ok, my bad I realize the output is an array of arrays, I just need to figure out how to extract them as separate arrays now, will try it, thanks !

Comment: Well, that was deliberate. Your names newArray1, newArray2, etc. were a big part of your problem. Any time you have names thing1, thing2, thing3, etc., that should be an array of thing. Seriously, do it my way.

Comment: yeah done it your way, I just then assigned variables names to each array element because I need further control over them for upcoming functions that will modify those arrays, append values and interpret them ;) thanks again !